# I can't see half may model in edit mode after applying symmetrize

Tags: mirror

So I have a symmetrical model but not arranged perfectly symmetrical after editing for some time. I applied the symmetrize function (not mirror modifier), and it worked in object mode, I can see my object perfectly symmetrical, but when I go to edit mode, half my model isn't showing.

I checked the modifiers, and nothing is there. I tried alt+h but I doesn't seem like anything is hiding.

Does anyone know what's happening. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, you say that Symmetrize worked in Object mode but actually it works in Edit mode, so what you say is not clear

Comment: I can see my object perfectly symmetrical in object mode.

Comment: Yes but you need to be in Edit mode to use the Symmetrize tool, so you should see the symmetry in Edit mode when you do the operation... but maybe show some screenshots or share your file? http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you, it seems like it's as you said, I might have done it in object mode, and have a different effect.

Comment: You can't do it in Object mode so you must have done something else, anyway, good if your problem is fixed  ;)

Comment: You're right because a shape key was selected the one half was pasted onto the other, making me think it wasn't there.